# Stuttering DataGridView in VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a datatable with hundred of rows, the database is a simple flatfile database written to a txt file. Whenever I scroll to the bottom the DGV starts stuttering. I am thinking of solutions but cannot find a way to code them

Here are my proposed solution:

- Use Paging to lessen the numbers of row being rendered. Here's is a [similar solution](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_paging.htm) but they are using sql
- Using doublebuffer which I've never touched before. I've tried doing DGV.doublebuffer = true but it said DGV is protected

Any help or clarification on my problem are greatly appreciated

Edit: Here is a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whs8k.png) of how my DGV is stutteting

The Datatable is named `Tbl_Sample`

Here is how I insert rows of data into data table. It gets data using `System.IO` on the Flatfile database(.txt file), split each line then send it to `InputTbl` as a row

```
Public Sub Update_Table(InputTbl As DataTable, InputFile As String)
    InputTbl.Rows.Clear()
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim vals() As String
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(InputFile)
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        vals = lines(i).ToString().Split("|")
        Dim row(vals.Length - 1) As String
        For j = 0 To vals.Length - 1
            row(j) = vals(j).Trim()
        Next j
        InputTbl.Rows.Add(row)
    Next i
End Sub
```

I set the table as Data Source for the DGV by `DGV.DataSource = Tbl_Sample`

The Datatable is created as Follow

```
 Public Sub Sample_Table()
    'Method For creating database file
    Create_DBFile("Sample.db")

    Try
        Tbl_Sample.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        Tbl_Sample.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Tbl_Sample.Columns.Add("Username", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Tbl_Sample.Columns.Add("Account_Type", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Tbl_Sample.Columns.Add("Date", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Tbl_Sample.Columns.Add("Time", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Update_Table(Tbl_Sample, "Sample.db") 'populate table
End Sub
```

*The way I create columns is not the best. I just copied it from my old program*

Comment: Can you show a [mre] that reproduces this “stuttering” you describe? Are there any grid events subscribed to that may be causing this “Stuttering”?

Comment: Could you add the code to load the datasource for this DVG too.  I've seen DVG work with hundreds of thousands of rows with no visible issue I've noticed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated my post, hope it helps you understand what my problem is. I'll be updating the post If ever you need clarifications again. Thank.

Comment: Unfortunately, your posted code does not reproduce the “stuttering” you describe. I tested the posted code with over 12,000 rows and it worked as expected without stuttering. The picture (png) you posted does not show this “stuttering” either… Something else must be going on that you are not showing. As I previously mentioned, are there any events that the grid subscribes to?

Comment: @JohnG I've found a solution. Apparently loading huge amount a data could make the DGV slow and cause it to flicker not stutter. The solution is using doublebuffer but I've been approaching it in the wrong way thinking a single line code can enable doublebuffer. I am sorry about the picture if it makes my problem harder to understand, it is supposed to be a GIF not PNG. BTW There are no events attached to my DVG if you're speaking about events on properties tab. I am sorry  for the lack of info, I am new to programming and its community. Thanks!

Comment: _"Apparently loading huge amount a data could make the DGV slow and cause it to flicker not stutter."_ ... ? ... Then why does my test using your code with over 12,000 rows not stutter as you describe?

Comment: Might be PC performance issue. I definitely doesn't know. My PC currently have 8 Gb of RAM with AMD 3400GE CPU and frequently runs with about 2gb of free ram according to task manager. I have the same problem on a test program I made on the same PC with nothing changed on DGV, all defaults. If I scroll fast enough to the bottom of the table (which is a frequent action done by users) the stutter/flicker starts to kick in. Scrolling slowly will not make the same effect tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution link [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1111155/Enable-DataGridView-DoubleBuffered-Property)

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Sub EnableDoubleBuffered(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim dgvType As Type = dgv.[GetType]()
    Dim pi As PropertyInfo = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", _
                                             BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    pi.SetValue(dgv, True, Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    EnableDoubleBuffered(MyDataGridView, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).